# weird integral precalculus

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

info: precalculus covers basic calculus second semester like derivatives and integral

So we got this one on final review $\displaystyle I=\int_{|x|=4}(x+1)^3\,dx.$

So I was thinking, first of all, why is there no upper bound, then I thought maybe it just meant integrate at $x=-4$ and $x=4$, and then I realized that made no sense either. Then I realized complex numbers have the absolute value (distance from $0$) property, so this might have just been a circle of radius $4$.

So using that logic, $\displaystyle I=\int_0^{2π}(4\cos(\theta)+4i\sin(\theta)+1)^3\,d\theta$.

Is this logic correct or nah?

Because from here the integration should be simple (even if it is a bit bashy)

Comment: Does $x$ represent a complex number?

Comment: i guess so, otherwise i would just be integrating at two points and that doesnt even make sense @user49640 but in complex space it represents a circle

Comment: To be well-defined as a complex integral, a direction would need to be specified on the circle. In that case, the integral is zero by Cauchy's theorem. (Your expression is incorrect, because if $x = e^{i\theta}$ as you have written, then $dx = ie^{i\theta} d\theta$.) Integrating at $x = -4$ and $x = 4$ is technically possible, and the answer would also be zero. Another possibility is that it could be a typo for $|x| \leq 4$.

Comment: So i would have $\displaystyle \int_0^{2π} ie^{i\theta}(e^{i\theta}+1)^3\,d\theta?$

Comment: That's right. And the answer ought to be zero. You can find this directly by expanding and evaluating the integral of $e^{in\theta}$ for integral values of $n$. If I may ask, why are you calling this "precalculus"?

Comment: because this is my precalculus class @user49640

Comment: But integrals are part of calculus, not "precalculus"! Would you mind telling me more about your class in Chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60343/discussion-between-user49640-and-saketh-malyala).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day: I'm not sure how to interpret this either. In the context of complex analysis, this expression would be interpreted as a contour integral around the circle $|x| = 4$ in the complex plane. The expression
$$ \displaystyle I=\int_0^{2π}(4\cos(\theta)+4i\sin(\theta)+1)^3\,d\theta $$
you wrote is *almost* what a contour integral is, but you need to replace $d\theta$ with $dx$ or, more correctly, with
$$ \frac{dx}{d\theta} \, d\theta = \frac{d}{d\theta} \Big(4\cos\theta+4i\sin\theta \Big)\,d\theta $$
because the original integral is in terms of $x$, but your bounds are $0$ and $2\pi$ which are in terms of $\theta$.

However, this is *probably* not what the question is asking. For one, it would be a question from complex analysis, or the calculus of complex numbers, which is something I doubt you'd be dealing with in ordinary *real* calculus. Moreover, the integral is actually trivial to evaluate using tools from complex analysis (it's zero), which would make it a somewhat silly question to ask in a complex analysis setting.

My best guess is the expression
$$ \displaystyle I=\int_{|x|=4}(x+1)^3\,dx $$
is meant to mean the real integral from $-4$ ***to*** $+4$ (as opposed to, as you say, "at" $-4$ and $+4$ which doesn't make sense to me either) because the equation $|x|=4$ has exactly two real solutions: $\pm 4$, and you need two bounds to evaluate a real definite integral. But it's only a guess. If it's correct, I'd like to have a word with whoever invented that terrible notation...

Comment: yeah i asked my teacher, she meant complex numbers. we are integrating precalculus and calculus, so we start with basic derivatives integrals, then when we learn about vectors, we do a little bit of vector calculus with that flux and curl with stokes&green theorem, some multiple integrals and when we do complex numbers we're starting complex analysis. this was a challenge problem, so we were supposed to kind of guess this